# How do I center my background image within my TD?

Tags: html, background-image, html-table, center

This is what I have so far. I have a style sheet created but I can't get it to display right through it either.

```
<td width="40%" background="images/form2.png" background-size="40%" repeat="no-repeat no-repeat" attachment="fixed" alignment="center" alt="">
    <div class="callform">CALL NOW!<br>
        1-877-670-9168<BR>or<BR>Let Us Call You
    </div>
    <div class="form2">Simply fill out the form below and one of our experts will call you.</div>
 </td>  
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td><div class="form">First name:</div></td>
         <td><input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"></td></tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last name: </td>
         <td><input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"></td></tr>     
      <tr>
         <td>Phone: </td>
         <td><input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"></td></tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Zip Code:</td>
         <td><input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"></td></tr>
  </table>
  <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
```

Comment: Please format your code and put the inline styles into a stylesheet then try editing your post with it

Comment: Yea I don't know what I'm doing, please help!

Comment: [Click here before you post your next question.](http://s.tk/onhold)

Comment: I've no idea how many times i shared this link in SO already, but here you go - [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: please post also your css

Comment: Yall have cleaned my code up, which is wonderful. But the BG image still isn't centering or not repeating itself within the <TD>

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by using CSS
you can find more on :

> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

First of all the code is bad...
I'll suggest you not to use `div` inside of the `td` at the moment.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gxQTs/3/
Note that the html code stills not appropriate!!

#### HTML:

```
    <div class="main">
    <img src="http://www.brendabaran.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Contact_Us.jpg">
        <div class="info">
        CALL NOW!
        1-877-670-9168<BR>or<BR>
        Let Us Call You
        </div>
Simply fill out the form below and<BR>one of our experts will call you.
  <div class="form">
     <form>
First name: <input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"><br>
Zip Code: <input type="text" size="50%" name="firstname"><br>
        <div class="submit" style="text-align:center;"> 
           <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
img
{
resize: both;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
left: 85px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

As you can see, you can move the image by the "`left`" property also `z-index:-1` sets the image to be overlapped by the form.